# How to Get ToDo Task List sharings and Task Groups from Exchange with EWS?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices, outlook-restapi, microsoft365, microsoft-exchange

Is it possible to get the permissions on a shared task list with EWS or Graph API? Also, how to get the Task Groups via API?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of today, it is not possible to get To-do Tasks sharing information and folder groups from any of EWS and Graph APIs.

The fields that are available for sharing on Graph are "isOwner" and "isShared"

[todoTaskList resource type - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/resources/todotasklist?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)

if the user is the owner of the given task list, then `isOwner: True`.

if the task list is shared with other users, then `isShared: True`.

Comment: That's what I thought too. Thanks @Karan.